# use funtion of framework c/c++ to project android studio

Tags: android, audio

I need to use the `setParameter` function of the `android.media.MediaPlayer` library. However, this is a "private native" function. I then found this function in a C ++ language framework. Is there a way to use this function? I want to control the sound track of the .ts file (left, right, mono).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setParameter is a hidden method.
Hidden methods are methods , they are marked with a @hide annotation.

You can use hidden method in different ways.

1.Using reflection

if you really want to use reflection, retrieve a Method object with:

```
Method m = YourClass.class.getMethod("method_name",new Class[] { Integer.class }) 
m.invoke(null,123);
```

In your case(not tested,may be some change will need):

```
Object mp = MediaPlayer.newInstance();
Method m = MediaPlayer.class.getMethod("setParameter",new Class[] { Integer.class,Integer.class }) 
m.invoke(mp,123,123);
```

2.Using android Hidden API library

https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api

Use this library.

Comment: Thanks, I tried  Its able to call hidden methods using reflection.

Comment: @Pain-PlusTeam : if this answer helps you,please accept and up-vote this answer.

Comment: i'm trying. wait for me some minute